# How to read the current value of MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

How can I read the current value of the MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU setting from code, i.e. for the current application pool? I don't mean reading it literally from a config file, but rather read the "resolved" value that is currently effective, regardless of where it was set  (i.e. registry, machine.config, web.config...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read

```
 System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU
```

This only works for .NET 4.x